# OS X Application Pop Up Menu

Tags: swift, macos

I have a custom image button. I want to display a custom menu when clicked on it. 
I am using

```
settingMenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(settingMenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation: NSEvent.mouseLocation(), inView: nil )
```

I created a menu and created an outlet for it. Still I am not able to see the menu

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-2)
if let button = statusItem.button {
  button.image = NSImage(named: "ButtonImageHere")
  button.action = Selector("actionForClickingButtonHere:")
}

func actionForClickingButtonHere(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Present view, show menu list, whatever
}
```

If you want to hide the dock icon do this in `Info.plist`:
[image]

For full example see [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps).